# How to achieve Freeze Pane in excel using office js api?

Tags: office-js

Our add-in create new sheet with ~300 columns. Users want the ability to freeze pane on first 2 columns, so when they move to the right, they still can see the context. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This feature is now available in Beta. Please switch to CDN to access this. 
`https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js`

Sample:

```
async function freezeColumns() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");

        // Freeze the first two columns in the worksheet.
        sheet.freezePanes.freezeColumns(2);

        //// Similarly, Freeze the top two rows in the worksheet.
        // sheet.freezePanes.freezeRows(2);
        //// Freeze the specified range in top-and-left-most pane of the worksheet.
        // sheet.freezePanes.freezeAt(sheet.getRange("H2:K5"));


        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

Unfreeze:

```
async function unfreezeAllPanes() {
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    sheet.freezePanes.unfreeze();

    await context.sync();
    });
}
```

Get location:

```
const frozenRange = sheet.freezePanes.getLocationOrNullObject();
frozenRange.load("address");
```

Comment: Probably can remove the `beta` comment!

Comment: P1 for actual code examples, to many link only answers to the docs in the `office-js` tags answers.

Comment: Note: I tried `freezeAt` w/ a single cell range and it hide the top of the WS. Using `rows` and `columns` worked as expected tho.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time we don't have this functionality available in our APIs, but thanks for your feedback and we will consider it for our future waves of new functionality.

Regards,
Philip, Developer on the Office Extensibility Team

Comment: Are there any APIs to copy a sheet? What I am thinking is, if I have a template with freeze pane already in it, can I copy the sheet and write the data into it? Will this approach work?

Comment: @renil Not at this point in time, though we may add it in the near future. You can find the complete set of APIs here http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office

Comment: Ability to copy sheets will be a great addition. Users will have to wait to freeze pane ☺