# Freeze top row office-js

Tags: excel, office-js

I was wondering if it is posible to freeze the top row of an excel sheet using the office-js api

within excel this feature, aplogies for the dutch installation.
[image: Block/freeeze top row]

Comment: This feature is now available in office-js. Please check the response to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762005/how-to-achieve-freeze-pane-in-excel-using-office-js-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available now.  Here's an example.

```
async function freeze_demo(){

  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");

    // Remove all frozen panes from a worksheet
    sheet.freezePanes.unfreeze()

    // Freeze the specified range in top-and-left-most pane of the worksheet.
    sheet.freezePanes.freezeAt(sheet.getRange("a1:c2"));

    // Freeze the top row
    //sheet.freezePanes.freezeRows(1);

    //Freeze the left two columns
    //sheet.freezePanes.freezeColumns(2);
    await context.sync();
  });

}
```

By the way, there is now an add-in that allows you to develop Excel automations in JavaScript without needing to host an add-in.  It's called JADE ().  To test this code, install JADE (search for JADE in the Excel Add-in Store to install), add a code module, and paste in the code.  Disclaimer: I wrote JADE

Answer (score 4):

This is not available yet; but definitely is on the road-map. I'll update this thread with the specs and some estimate of the date when it is available. 
One could also follow the open-spec branches of the [OfficeJS repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs) to get a view into new features coming along.